# Receiving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected error when attempting to log into Wordpress admin. log in

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, syntax

I updated 2 plug-ins as my WordPress admin. suggested doing this this morning. (have done in past with no problem) This site now no longer appears and even worse I am now unable to log into the WordPress admin for that site.
The error message I receive is this:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home2/domainname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/everest-forms/includes/fields/class-evf-field-date-time.php at line 707`

I substituted the domain name for what is had for my username. I apologize if am not wording my question correctly per your rules or am not explaining very well. Unfortunately am a bit of a dummy in regards to this. Any help would be very, very much appreciated.

Comment: Via ftp. Go to the plugins folder and rename the plug-in causing your problem. This will allow you to get back into your admin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is really appreciated